# What is does this error method mean: undefined method `method name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am fairly new to automation testing and I am writing BDD automation test scenarios in Ruby using selenium-webdriver, when running my tests, they fail at the first step. (tumblr just as an example)

What does this error message mean and how do I fix it? Any help would be much appreciated!

**In my feature file:**

```
  Feature: tumblr 
    @s1
  Scenario: Logging in to Tumblr
    Given I am on the Tumblr login page
    When I enter my login details
    Then I should be sent to the dashboard
```

**In my login_page.rb:**

```
def visit
  @browser.goto "#{EnvConfig.base_url}/login"
  await_on_page
end
```

**In my login_step_defs.rb:**

```
Given /^I am on the Odicci login page$/ do 
  @app.tumblr_login.visit
end

When /^I enter my login details$/ do 
  @app.tumblr_login.login
end

Then /^I should be sent to the dashboard$/ do 
  @app.tumblr_dashboard.go_to_dashboard
end
```

Initially when I was running 'cucumber features.feature' but the step definitions could not be located so the scenarios were finishing off as 'undefined' so running 'cucumber features.feature -r step_definitions works to run the tests but they fail because of this error message:

```
Scenario: Logging in to Tumblr           # features.feature:4
Given I am on the Tumblr login page    # step_definitions/login_step_defs.rb:2
  undefined method `tumblr_login' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  ./step_definitions/login_step_defs.rb:3:in `/^I am on the Tumblr login page$/'
  features.feature:5:in `Given I am on the Tumblr login page'
```

Comment: Your `@app` variable is `nil` (undefined) - where do you define it?

Comment: it means that `nil` object(in your case its `@app`) does not respond to `tumblr_login` method.

Comment: my @app is declared in my hooks.rb file

Comment: @dianaosmani it's not beinng loaded in any case. Can you show the hooks file?

Comment: I tried but because I have a lot of instance variables, it is reading them as stack overflow users. How can i send code in a comment? @maxpleaner

Comment: @dianaosmani it's impossible to read in a comment, add it to your question innstead :D

Answer (score 0):

@maxpleaner

```
if ENV['HEADLESS']
  require 'headless'
  require 'selenium-webdriver'
  headless = Headless.new display: '100'
  headless.start
end

# Set up browser
# browser = Watir::Browser.new (ENV['BROWSER'] || 'chrome').to_sym
 driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
 browser_type = ENV['BROWSER'] || 'chrome'
 $setup_done = false


Before do |scenario|

    @browser = browser
    @app = App.new @browser

    unless $setup_done
    $setup_done = true
    # This stuff will only run before the first scenario executed. Use it to set up data etc.
    end
end

After do |scenario|

end

at_exit do
    browser.quit
end
```